# Oracle data access output parameter mixed up

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, stored-procedures, output-parameter

I am invoking an Oracle stored procedure witch contains 15 input parameters and 4 output parameters. Output parameters are set like this:

```
OracleParameter p_errn = cmd.Parameters.Add("pErrCode", OracleDbType.Decimal, 10);
                p_errn.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                OracleParameter p_errm = cmd.Parameters.Add("pErrMsg", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 1000);
                p_errm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                OracleParameter pStatus = cmd.Parameters.Add("pStatus", OracleDbType.Decimal, 10); 
                pStatus.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                OracleParameter pID = cmd.Parameters.Add("pID", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 1000);
                pID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Procedure i successfully executed but output paramers values are mixed up. Value that should be in pId is in pStatus, value that should be in pStatus is in pErrMsg and so on.

I have also tried to get values by getting from Parameter collection:

```
cmd.Parameters["pErrMsg"].Value.ToString()
```

but the situation is the same.

I have checked stored procedure, an everything seems fine. All the output parameters are set correctly.

Anyone had similar problem or some hint what causes this behaviour?

Comment: check the order in which you are passing the parameter

Comment: I have checked that also, order is the same

Comment: did you try executing the same procedure in DB and get correct results

Comment: yes I did. i get the correct results

Comment: Are the data types correct for the parameters

Comment: yes, i have triple checked

Answer (score 0):

**All the parameters must be added in the same order as they are defined in stored procedure on ORACLE**.

One of the input parameters was added out of order and that caused the confusion.